# Count multiple parent divs that have child divs appended into them

Tags: jquery, count, append, counter

I'm appending many child divs from an "#originalsection" div container into multiple new ".newsection" div containers based on their class. I'm having trouble trying to code a counting mechanism for 4 divs per section.

The specific code I'm having trouble with is

```html
   div_count += 1;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```html
<div id="originalsection"></div>
<div id="red" class="newsection">
   <div id="section-0" class="child">
      <div class="red all"> A </div>
      <div class="red all"> D </div>
      <div class="red all"> G </div>
      <div class="red all"> J </div>
   </div>
   <div id="section-1" class="child">
      <div class="red all"> K </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="newsection">
   <div id="section-0" class="child">
      <div class="red all"> B </div>
      <div class="red all"> E </div>
      <div class="red all"> H </div>
      <div class="red all"> I </div>
   </div>
   <div id="section-1" class="child">
      <div class="red all"> L </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="green" class="newsection">
   <div id="section-0" class="child">
      <div class="red all"> C </div>
      <div class="red all"> F </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My current code is:

```html
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      var div_count = 0;
      var section_count = 0;
      var $all = $('#all');

      $('div#originalsection div').each(function() {
         var $div = $(this);
         var sectionclass = $div.attr('class').split(' ')[0];

         if ($("#section-"+section_count).length == 0) {
            $('.newsection').append
            ('<div id="section-'+section_count+'" class="child"></section>');
         }
         var $classCount = $('#' + sectionclass + " #section-" + section_count);
         $classCount.append($div);

         // ***TRYING TO FIX THIS CODE BELOW***
         div_count += 1;

         if (div_count > 3) {  
            div_count = 0;  
            section_count += 1;   
         } 
      });
   });
</script>

<div id="originalsection">
   <div class="red all"> A </div>
   <div class="blue all"> B </div>    
   <div class="green all"> C </div>
   <div class="red all"> D </div>
   <div class="blue all"> E </div>
   <div class="green all"> F </div>
   <div class="red all"> G </div>
   <div class="blue all"> H </div>    
   <div class="blue all"> I </div>
   <div class="red all"> J </div>
   <div class="red all"> K </div>
   <div class="blue all"> L </div>  
</div>
<!--<div id="all" class="newsection"></div>-->
<div id="red" class="newsection"></div>
<div id="blue" class="newsection"></div>
<div id="green" class="newsection"></div>

<style>
   #red { color: red; }
   #green { color: green; }
   #blue { color: blue; }
   .child { border: 1px solid green; width: 50px; margin: 5px;}
</style>
```

---

Like I mentioned above, the code I'm trying to change is

```html
   div_count += 1;
```

because (i think) it is counting every time a div is appended into any of the ".newsection" div rather than counting the number of divs in a single ".newsection" divs.

I think the solution is writing something with the equivalence of:
"if ('#' sectionclass + "#section-" + section_count) gets a div appended, div_count += 1"

I'm sure this involves.length code. I've tried:

```html
var $classCount.find('div') = $('#' + sectionclass + " #section-" + section_count);
if ($classCount.length += 1 ) {
   div_count += 1;
}
```

I'm still a beginner code. I greatly appreciate any explanations. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use id like this id="section-0". Id should be unique. You can put this into a class instead. You can store counter for each color in an object and increment it every time you append a child div. Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = {};
        var i = 0;
        $('#originalsection div').each(function () {
            var sectionclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            console.log(sectionclass);
            if (typeof (counter[sectionclass]) == 'undefined') {
                counter[sectionclass] = {};
                counter[sectionclass]['color'] = 0;
                counter[sectionclass]['suffix'] = 0;
            } else {
                counter[sectionclass]['color']++;
            }

            if (counter[sectionclass]['color'] % 4 == 0) {
                if (counter[sectionclass]['color'] != 0) {
                    counter[sectionclass]['suffix']++;
                }
                $('#' + sectionclass).append('<div class="child section-' + counter[sectionclass]['suffix'] + '"></div>');

            }

            $('#' + sectionclass + ' .section-' + counter[sectionclass]['suffix']).append($(this));




        });

    });
```